# DAGs not clickable on Google Cloud Composer webserver, but working fine on a local Airflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I'm using [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) (managed Airflow on Google Cloud Platform) with image version `composer-0.5.3-airflow-1.9.0` and Python 2.7, and I'm facing a weird issue : after importing my DAGs, they are **not clickable** from the Web UI (and there are no buttons "Trigger DAG", "Graph view", ...), while all works perfectly when running a local Airflow.

Even if non usable from the webserver on Composer, my DAGs still exist. I can list them using CLI (`list_dags`), describe them (`list_tasks`) and even trigger them (`trigger_dag`).

### Minimal example reproducing the issue

A minimal example I used to reproduce the issue is shown below. Using a hook (here, `GoogleCloudStorageHook`) is very important, since the bug on Composer happens when a hook is used. Initially, I was using a custom hook (in a custom plugin), and was facing the same issue.

Basically here, the example lists all entries in a GCS bucket (`my-bucket`) and generate a DAG for each entry beginning with `my_dag`.

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

google_conn_id = 'google_cloud_default'

gcs_conn = GoogleCloudStorageHook(google_conn_id)

bucket = 'my-bucket'
prefix = 'my_dag'

entries = gcs_conn.list(bucket, prefix=prefix)

for entry in entries:
    dag_id = str(entry)

    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        start_date=datetime.datetime.today(),
        schedule_interval='0 0 1 * *'
    )

    op = BashOperator(
        task_id='test',
        bash_command='exit 0',
        dag=dag
    )

    globals()[dag_id] = dag
```

#### Results on Cloud Composer

After importing this file to Composer, here's the result (I have 4 files beginning with `my_dag` in `my-bucket`) :

[image: DAGs on Google Cloud Composer]

As I explained, DAGs are not clickable and the columns "Recent Tasks" and "DAG Runs" are loading forever. The "info" mark next to each DAG name says : `This DAG isn't available in the webserver DagBag object. It shows up in this list because the scheduler marked it as active in the metadata database`.

Of course, refreshing is not useful, and when accessing the DAG Graph View by the direct URL (`https://****.appspot.com/admin/airflow/graph?dag_id=my_dag_1`), it shows an error : `DAG "my_dag_1" seems to be missing.`

#### Results on local Airflow

When importing the script on a local Airflow, the webserver works fine :

[image: DAGs on local Airflow]

### Some tests

If I replace the line `entries = gcs_conn.list(bucket, prefix=prefix)` with hard-coded values like `entries = [u'my_dag_1', u'my_dag_2', u'my_dag_3', u'my_dag_4']`, then DAGs are clickable on Composer Web UI (and all buttons on "links" columns appear). It seems that, from other tests I have made on my initial problem, *calling a method from a hook* (not just initializing the hook) causes the issue. Of course, DAGs in Composer work normally on simple examples (no hooks method calls involved).

I have no idea why this happened, I have also inspected the logs (by setting `logging_level = DEBUG` in `airflow.cfg`) but could not see something wrong. I'm suspecting a bug in the webserver, but I cannot get a significant stack trace. Webserver logs from Composer (hosted on App Engine) are not available, or at least I did not find a way to access them.

Did someone experienced the same issue or similar ones with Composer Web UI ? I think the problem is coming from the usage of hooks, but I may be wrong. It can just be a side effect. To be honest, I am lost after testing so many things. I'll be glad if someone can help me. Thanks!

### Update

When deploying a self-managed webserver on Kubernetes following this guide : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver, my DAGs are clickable from this self-managed webserver.

Comment: I am not familiar with Composer, but are both components (webserver and scheduler) running? Are the paths setup correctly?

Comment: @tobi6 Yes, both are running and managed by Composer. There is no way to restart them also. I'm not sure what you mean by "paths setup correctly", but Airflow configuration is done by Google when provisioning an environment. What is weird is that it works correctly on simple examples (involving no hooks method calls).

Comment: When I had an issue like that, the DAG files got deployed the first time but the second time I messed up and the files were in a wrong folder. If Google does it all, I suppose the folders are correct but I suspect this might be connected to the files. Maybe incorrect ownership or some setup issue?

Comment: Sometimes, Airflow will instantiate a DAG in the db with some sort of python issue that will prevent the DAG from actually running, leaving you with unclickable DAGs in the UI. Can you recreate this problem in regular Airflow?

Comment: @tobi6 I'm sure there is no problem about the files, since replacing `entries` with hard-coded values instead of calling the hook method (as I showed in the Tests section) works.

@VirajParekh Actually no, I can't reproduce the problem with my local Airflow install, and that's my main concern! So I think this bug is related to Composer, but I can't find something relevant in the logs :(

Comment: Maybe the Airflow component has no rights to create files but only to read them. Is there any extended setup in Composer where you could set those rights?

Comment: @tobi6 There is no such thing; manual configuration of Composer environments is very limited, only trivial operations are allowed, like setting environment variables. But suppose you're right and there is a rights issue, what involves file(s) creation in my DAGs definition? Moreover, why simply commenting the line doing the hook method call is sufficient to make the DAGs clickable on the Web UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Composer webserver runs with a different service account than the nodes in the Composer GKE cluster. You should make sure you have assigned the appropriate role/permissions to your webserver's service account.

E.g. if your webserver's url is:

```
foo-tp.appspot.com
```

then the service account is:

```
foo-tp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, it is weird that this service account is not automatically created when the Composer environment is created. Do you know how can we manage other permissions, like for example access to a self-hosted database on Compute? It is easy for Google Storage (Storage Viewer role), but it seems more difficult for non-managed tools.

Comment: Hi guys, can you explain it in more detail? I have the same issue with the dag is not clickable. Where would I assign the webserver service account?

Comment: @TuanVu just create the service account and the webserver should use it, without specifying something else

Comment: @norbjd Is it as simple as creating this service account after the composer environment is up? I am facing the same issue and cannot figure out why composer would neglect something as crucial as this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this just isn't the same problem, or if I don't understand the answer. Are you suggesting that `gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:b1ccd38045a27e929-tp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer gs://my-bucket` is what is needed if my airflow server is https://b1ccd38045a27e929-tp.appspot.com/ ? Because granting `objectViewer` doesn't seem to have changed anything for me.