# Dynamically Creating DAG based on Row available on DB Connection

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to create a dynamically created DAG from database table query. When I'm trying to create a dynamically creating DAG from both of range of exact number or based on available object in airflow settings it's succeeded. However when I'm trying to use a PostgresHook and create a DAG for each of row of my table, I can see a new DAG generated whenever I add a new row in my table. However it turned out that I can't click the newly created DAG on my airflow web server ui. For more context I'm using Google Cloud Composer. I already following the steps mentioned in [DAGs not clickable on Google Cloud Composer webserver, but working fine on a local Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218314/dags-not-clickable-on-google-cloud-composer-webserver-but-working-fine-on-a-loc/51386238#51386238). However it's still not working for my case.

Here's my code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
import psycopg2
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor
import os

default_args = {
  "owner": "debug",
  "depends_on_past": False,
  "start_date": datetime(2018, 10, 17),
  "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
  "email_on_failure": False,
  "email_on_retry": False,
  "retries": 1,
  "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
# 'queue': 'bash_queue',
# 'pool': 'backfill',
# 'priority_weight': 10,
# 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}


def create_dag(dag_id,
           schedule,
           default_args):
def hello_world_py(*args):
    print 'Hello from DAG: {}'.format(dag_id)

dag = DAG(dag_id,
          schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
          default_args=default_args)

with dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id=dag_id,
        python_callable=hello_world_py,
        dag_id=dag_id)

return dag


dag = DAG("dynamic_yolo_pg_", default_args=default_args,     
        schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1))

"""
Bahavior:
Create an exact DAG which in turn will create it's own file
https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/
"""
pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='some_db')
conn = pg_hook.get_conn()
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM airflow_test_command;")
commands = cursor.fetchall()
for command in commands:
  dag_id = command.id
  schedule = timedelta(days=1)

  id = "dynamic_yolo_" + str(dag_id)

  print id

  globals()[id] = create_dag(id,
                           schedule,
                           default_args)
```

Best,

Comment: Please show us what code you tried, for example the postgres hook.

Comment: Hi I already post the code, thanks. I think it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218314/dags-not-clickable-on-google-cloud-composer-webserver-but-working-fine-on-a-loc/51386238#51386238

However the problem still persist :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be solved using self-managed Airflow Webserver using steps mentioned in [1]. After you do this, if you decide to add authentication in front of your self-managed webserver, once you created the ingress, your BackendServices should appear on the Google IAP console and you can enable the IAP. In case you want to access your airflow programmatically you also can use JWT authentication using service account for your self-managed Airflow Webserver [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver

[2] https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto